# Getting partial data scraping site with scrapy, whereas same url gets me full results from the shell

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to scrape Groupon deals using the following [link](https://www.groupon.fr/browse/paris?category=bars-et-restaurants&=undefined&gclid=Cj0KCQjwo7foBRD8ARIsAHTy2wm4-T4w6ps1KMDg5eG8S7jDsNco8VxuJIcoQO6OXkSrzQm4TWEe-QkaArFXEALw_wcB&utm_campaign=fr_dt_sea_ggl_txt_naq_sr_cbp_ch1_ybr_k*groupon%2Bparis_m*e_d*Groupon-Paris_g*Paris-Exact_c*96685051824_ap*1t1&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&page0):

When I run that from the shell `scrapy shell` I see all deals on the page.
e.g. `titles = response.css('figure.card-ui').css('div.cui-udc-title-with-subtitle ::text').getall()` gets me 37 titles.

Shell run gets me:

```
>>> titles = response.css('figure.card-ui').css('div.cui-udc-title-with-subtitle ::text').getall()
>>> titles = [ title.rstrip().lstrip()  for title in titles ]
>>> len(titles)
37
>>> titles
[u'Le Bar du Normandy - H\xf4tel Normandy', u'Michel Balmet', u'Passion Chocolat', u'Le Caf\xe9 Clairi\xe8re', u'LES CAVES DU LOUVRE', u"L'artiste Restaurant", u'Auberge Le Relais', u'Le Caf\xe9 des Initi\xe9s', u'La Mar\xe9e (75008)', u'Ko\xef', u'Casa Paco (75116)', u'Capitaine Fracasse', u'LePergol\xe8se', u'Wine Tours Paris', u'La Maison Du Rhum', u'Au Port du Salut', u'Grains Nobles', u"L'artiste Restaurant", u'Michel Balmet, 10e', u'Feyrouz C\xf4t\xe9 Mer', u"L'agap\xe9", u"Restaurant Au Bon'art", u'Shibuya Karaok\xe9', u'Eiffel Croisieres', u'Cfv', u'Made In Italy', u'Fuumi Restaurant', u'OfbPontault', u'Le Jackpot', u'La Brasserie Centrale', u'Le cheval blanc', u'LA CANTINE DES TSARS', u'Restaurant Guy Savoy \xe0 la Monnaie de Paris', u'Chez Ma Cousine', u'MAMABALI', u'LE COSMOS', u'Restaurant Le Sancerre']
>>>
```

When I run this from a scraper I only get a small subset of the results:

```
class GrouponSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "deals"

    start_urls = [
            'https://www.groupon.fr/browse/paris?category=bars-et-restaurants&=undefined&gclid=Cj0KCQjwo7foBRD8ARIsAHTy2wm4-T4w6ps1KMDg5eG8S7jDsNco8VxuJIcoQO6OXkSrzQm4TWEe-QkaArFXEALw_wcB&utm_campaign=fr_dt_sea_ggl_txt_naq_sr_cbp_ch1_ybr_k*groupon%2Bparis_m*e_d*Groupon-Paris_g*Paris-Exact_c*96685051824_ap*1t1&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&page0'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.css('figure.card-ui').css('div.cui-udc-title-with-subtitle ::text').getall()
        titles = [ title.rstrip().lstrip()  for title in titles ]
        for title in titles:
            yield { 'title' : title }

    next_page = response.css('a.next::attr(href)').get()

    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

In that case I get the following (running with flags `-o items.csv -t csv`), which is a small subset of all results:

```
$ cat items.csv
    title
    Le Bar du Normandy - Hôtel Normandy
    Michel Balmet
    Passion Chocolat
    Le Café Clairière
    Auberge Le Relais
    La Marée (75008)
    L'artiste Restaurant
```

Any idea regarding how to get full results from the scraper code?

Comment: Could you please explain how many does you subset results contain ?

Comment: Added data I get from running it

Comment: Same behavior on my end. To fix it try to navigate first to https://www.groupon.fr/ and then to your link. I believe that there are some cookie shenanigans going on.

Comment: Interestingly, I get correct response with `curl` command and `requests` library, but I cannot get it with `scrapy` (both with shell and spider).

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding a sleep() before checking the "next" link. which sort of indicates that the loop over the deals ends before the full document is loaded, and the "next" link is already there.